# Type punning in a const / static initializer (building a float constant from bits)

Tags: c++, type-punning

Some languages (like Rust, Zig, GLSL, HLSL) have built-in methods to build a floating type from bits supplied as an unsigned integer. However C and C++ do not have standard functions for that.

With C99 we can use anonymous unions with member initialization to implement a type punning macro to the same effect:

```
#define FLOAT_FROM_BITS(U,F,b) (((union{U u; F f;}){.u=(b)}).f)
#define FLOAT32_FROM_BITS(i) FLOAT_FROM_BITS(uint32_t, float,  i)
#define FLOAT64_FROM_BITS(i) FLOAT_FROM_BITS(uint64_t, double, i)
```

which can then subsequently be used to initialize const / static with. What would be the most elegant way to do this in C++, so that it can also be used for static initialization?

Comment: Which version of C++ can you use?  C++20 comes with [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast)

Comment: @NathanOliver: C++20 is actually my current target profile. I wasn't aware of the existence of `std::bit_cast`. However for the sake of people who not yet can use it, I'd like to see other approaches, if those are possible.

Comment: You should be able to simply write the initialization as `constinit`, calling only `constexpr` function while doing that and the compiler will put in the right bit pattern for you. You might have to implement some math functions yourself if the compiler doesn't consider them constexpr, the standard is a bit lagging behind there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use C++20 or above, then use [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) like

```
auto myvar = std::bit_cast<type_to_cast_to>(value_to_cast);
```

If you want to support older versions, you can do this same thing using `std::memcpy` to copy the bytes from one type to another.  That would give you a function like

```
template <class To, class From>
To bit_cast(const From& src)
{
    To dst;
    std::memcpy(&dst, &src, sizeof(To));
    return dst;
}
```

Comment: But does memcpy work with static initialization? E.g. if I wanted to write something like `float const my_magic_constant = FLOAT_FROM_BITS(…);` ideally with the compiler just emitting the raw constant in the generated code.

Comment: Well, `constexpr` initialization is what I'm after.

Comment: @datenwolf It will work in that case, but most likely the function will run at run time, so no constant baked into your binary

Comment: @datenwolf In that case you need `std::bit_cast`.  You might be able to make your own, but you'll need to look into what intrinsics are available in your implementation and you might be able to make your own version using those.

Comment: Well, that's a bummer; the constant in question will be applied in the innermost loop of some DSP data conversion function. I kind of don't want to load that constant from memory (albeit, I guess once it's in the register it doesn't make a huge difference).

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to benchmark the two to see if it really matters to the performance.

Comment: @datenwolf How does constexpr initialisation affect "load from memory"?

Comment: @eerorika: The value I want to apply is a fixed constant with a specific bit pattern, that's known at compile time. Strictly speaking at code generation time, the compiler could just insert that specific bit pattern into the generated code as a constant value operand. Which would save loading a single word from memory. Now since this constant is used throughout a whole innermost loop that happens only once. But imagine that the algorithm consists of a lot such constants (more than registers available), then you'd run the danger of hitting memory latency issues (in case of L1 cache misses).

Comment: @eerorika: For a practical example of such "magic" constants look up the *fast inverse square root* algorithm (sometimes incorrectly attributed to Carmack, but is way older and we don't know who exactly was the mad genius who found that magic constant in the first place).

Comment: @datenwolf I did some experimenting, and it appears that GCC never uses `mov  eax, CONSTANT` with floats. It uses it only with integers. Even with a constexpr value, it uses `movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR .LCx[rip]` to load the value into a register. Only difference with using `std::memcpy` is that it copies the value into the memory on startup (using the same trick `mov     DWORD PTR c1[rip], CONSTANT`) instead of using the read-only segment.

Comment: @eerorika: I can confirm your results for x86[_64] for GCC, CLang and MSVC. However for AArch64 both GCC and Clang will emit immediate values for float32 and Clang also for float64 but not GCC: https://godbolt.org/z/Y4GTreaqb

Answer (score 1):

An elegant way is to use `std::bit_cast`:

```
std::uint64_t i = example_value();
auto d = std::bit_cast<double>(i);
```